# limsup and liminf are equal when...

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I have to prove the following:

> If $\forall n\in \mathbb N \colon { \cfrac { 1 }{ 100 } <{ a }_{ n } }$ then $\limsup\limits_{ n\to\infty  }\{ \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } } \} =\frac { 1 }{ \liminf_{ n\to \infty  }\{ { a }_{ n }\}  } $.

Can anyone give me any pointers on this one?

Comment: What is $\,f\,$ there...?

Comment: Please reach an acceptable statement (the present one is not). Once this will be done, please indicate your thoughts on the question.

Comment: What is lim of lim inf in the rightmost expression??

Comment: @Did, this should be right now.

Comment: There is no upper but lower bound: $\,100^{-1}\,$

Comment: OP: Right, so let us move to step 2: "please indicate your thoughts on the question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I strongly suggest to read [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) before going further. Anyway, the statement to prove is actually the following:

> Let $u\gt0$ and $(a_n)_n$ a real-valued sequence such that $a_n\geqslant u$ for every $n$. For every $n$, let $b_n=1/a_n$. Let $A=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $B=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$. Show that $B=1/A$.

To prove this, first note that $a_n\geqslant u$ for every $n$ guarantees that $A\geqslant u$, thus $A\gt0$ (this will be the only use of the hypothesis that  $a_n\geqslant u$ for every $n$, for some $u\gt0$).

**First case:** $A$ is infinite. Then $a_n\to+\infty$ hence $b_n\to0$, which implies that $B=0$. Done, if one accepts that $B=1/A$ when $B=0$ and $A=+\infty$.

**Second case:** $A$ is finite.

- Let $A'\gt A$. By definition of $\liminf$, there exists a subsequence $(a_{\varphi(n)})_n$ such that $a_{\varphi(n)}\leqslant A'$ for every $n$. Hence $b_{\varphi(n)}\geqslant1/A'$ for every $n$. Thus, $B\geqslant1/A'$.
- Let $A''\gt0$, $A''\lt A$ (this is where the hypothesis that $A\gt0$ is used). By definition of $\liminf$, there exists a finite $k$ such that $a_n\geqslant A''$ for every $n\geqslant k$. Hence $b_n\leqslant1/A''$ for every $n\geqslant k$. Thus, $B\leqslant1/A''$.
- One has $1/A'\leqslant B\leqslant1/A''$ for every $0\lt A''\lt A\lt A'$. Thus, $B=1/A$.

Note finally that the result holds for every positive sequence $(a_n)_n$ (even without the lower bound hypothesis) if one accepts that $B=1/A$ when $B=+\infty$ and $A=0$.

Comment: Thank you. That was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (I think).

I showed that if a sequence $a_n$ has a positive lower bound, then ${ \sup\{ \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } } \}  }=\frac { 1 }{\inf{\{a_n}\}}$, and it follows that $\limsup=\liminf$.

Proof:

> 1. $\forall n\quad { a }_{ n }>\frac { 1 }{ 100 } \Rightarrow \exists i\in \Re \quad s.t.\quad i=inf\{ { a }_{ n }\} \quad \quad$
> 2. ${ a }_{ n }\ge i\ge \frac { 1 }{ 100 } \Rightarrow 100\ge \frac { 1 }{ i } \ge \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } } $ so the sequence $\{ \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } } \} $ is bounded above by $\frac { 1 }{ inf\{ { a }_{ n }\}  } $.
> 3. Let's say there exists a smaller upper bound: $\exists j\in \Re \quad s.t.\quad \frac { 1 }{ i } >\frac { 1 }{ j } \ge \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } } $.
> 4. It's all positive so this means: $i<j\le { a }_{ n } \Rightarrow i\neq inf\{ { a }_{ n }\}  \bot $
>
> <strike>*5. So $\frac { 1 }{ \inf\{ { a }_{ n }\} }= \sup{\{\frac{1}{{a }_{n}}}\}$, and it's easy to see from here that: $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ sup\left\{ \frac { 1 }{ { a }_{ n } }  \right\} =\frac { 1 }{ \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ inf\{  } { a }_{ n }\}  }  } $*</strike>

Comment: Once again, we cannot assert the validity of your approach if you do not write down your proof here.

Comment: @Did Here and thanks for your patience.

Comment: I am not sure this will convince your TA... First of all, you might be confused about the statement to be proven, which seems to be $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}1/a_n=1/\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$, and not what you write.

Comment: Please read [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).

Comment: I see that final part on line 5 is false. Do you think this (lines 1-4) is the right angle?